# `echo $0` returns full path instead of dash-prefixed shell in VS Code

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, echo, zsh

I'm running VS Code on macOS (10.13.6 if it matters). Here's what I get in its integrated terminal:

```
$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

But in the macOS Terminal app, I get:

```
$ echo $0
-bash
```

I've seen that the [dash prefix means it's a login shell](https://superuser.com/a/278865/1115114). Is this not the case with VS Code? Here it says that's [the default for macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_powershell-on-macos-is-complaining-about-a-l-argument-how-do-i-fix-it).

I've been playing with changing the Login Shell to `/bin/zsh`, and then to `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to use an install from Homebrew. This caused some confusion.

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: It's the default for MacOS *when its Terminal launches a shell*. Not default *everywhere* in MacOS.

Comment: anyhow, what's your actual goal? If you want to know if the current shell is a login shell, the reliable way to test that is `[[ $- = *l* ]]` (or, more portably, `case $- in *l*) echo "Yes, it's a login shell";; *) echo "No, it's not a login shell";; esac`), nothing to do with `$0` at all.

Comment: ...similarly, if you want to know if the current shell is bash, the reliable way to test that is more like `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then echo "The current shell either is bash, or is run by someone who wants to pretend to be bash"; fi`. There really aren't many good use cases for `$0` at all -- see [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) describing how it's unsuitable even for the purpose folks all-too-often try to put it to of finding the location of the currently-running script.

Answer (score 0):

As per Charles comments, if you add some log/echo like:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then echo "The current shell either is bash, or is run by someone who wants to pretend to be bash"; fi
```

to the top of your .bashrc file when you open a new terminal you will have a  log which will therefore confirm that is the bashrc which has been loaded by your terminal applicaiton or vscode integrated terminal. If it is not logged then you will be loading a bash file from different location.

I think that you will find that both are the same.

Off question, but feel that this may alse be something that interests. If you have icon issues i.e. vscode has not loaded the icons that are available in termainal it may be because they are not available fonts and you will need to download them.

This is the solution from font.md on zsh-theme-powerlevel10k which will probably be similar in bash.

- **Visual Studio Code**: Open *File → Preferences → Settings* (PC) or
  *Code → Preferences → Settings* (Mac), enter `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` in the search box at
  the top of *Settings* tab and set the value below to `MesloLGS NF`.
  Consult [this screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/389133fb8c9a2347929a23702ce3039aacc46c3d/visual-studio-code-font-settings.jpg)
  to see how it should look like or see [this issue](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/671) for extra information.